# struts 2 param interceptor is not working fine if list contain more than 10 items?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have customerAtction which customer dataObject. Customer data object contains arraylist of orders.

If I have 10 order placed from ui then struts 2 works fine and i get  10 orders populated in my customer object

```
<input type='hidden'  name ='customer.orders[0].item' value ='someItem'/>// First item
                to
<input type='hidden'  name ='customer.orders[9].item' value ='someItem'/>// Tenth item
```

But if i have 11 items i cet customer object with 11 orders with first and last order correctly filled  but inbetween 9 orders are not correctly filled

```
<input type='hidden'  name ='customer.orders[0].item' value ='someItem'/>// First item
                to
 <input type='hidden'  name ='customer.orders[10].item' value ='someItem'/>// eleventh item
```

Some how param interceptor is not working fine for more than 10 items. I am not sure what i am missing here?

**Acion Code**

Here is brief about action class

```
CustomerOrderAction contains  
 private Customer   customer; // getters and setters

Customer contains
 private List<ShopItem>  orders   = new ArrayList<ShopItem>();

ShopItem contains
 public int      item           = -1; // getters and setters
```

Comment: which one is not filled correctly first and last or in between ? more over this seems to be an issue with your code and not with interceptors.

Comment: in between ones are filled as null

Comment: can u share action level code..?

Comment: @emily Post the relevant code where the orders is populated. Also how do you know which items are filled and which is not if they are have the *same* value.

Comment: The `item` type is int and you are putting strings in hidden value.

Comment: I just gave an exampleEven changing item type from int to string does not help

Comment: try changing the code to `<input type='hidden'  name ='customer.orders[].item' value ='someItem'/>` for all items